# Adjusting base graphics legend label width

Tags: r, legend

I have plotted six graphs using R.  They are arranged into 2 rows and 3 columns.
At the bottom of all these graphs, I want to create a legend which contains four lines with a name next to each line, i.e.

**------- aaaaaaa  -------bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  -------cccccc --------dddddd **

However, when I used the text.width function in legend, I couldn't figure out how I can work out values for text.width.  As you can see above, some legend names are longer (e.g.bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb) therefore would need more space.

### R code:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3),mar=c(4.5,4,1,1),oma=c(2,0,0,0)) #Setting the margins


plot(1,1,xlim=c(5,10.7),ylim=c(15,25))
plot(1,1,xlim=c(5,10.7),ylim=c(45,70))
plot(1,1,xlim=c(5,10.7),ylim=c(20,33))
plot(1,1,xlim=c(5,10.7),ylim=c(15,25))
plot(1,1,xlim=c(5,10.7),ylim=c(45,70))
plot(1,1,xlim=c(5,10.7),ylim=c(20,33))  # plot six graphs

labels<-c("aaaaa","bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb","ccccccccccc", "ddddd")  #legend labels
colour<-c("red","black","dark green","blue")#legend line colours

par(fig = c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0), new = TRUE) 
plot(0, 0, type = "n", bty = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")## create an empty plot

legend("bottom", lty=1,lwd=1.5,ncol=4,labels,cex=1,
col=colour,bg="white",pt.cex=1,bty="n",text.width=c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)) ## creating legend
```

Comment: The code you provided does not create plots. It's difficult to help with plotting code if the the problem isn't easily reproducible. It can be as simple as `plot(1,1)` but make sure all the variable are defined as well.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear code.  I have now edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is kind of tricky because while `legend` accepts a vector of different lengths for `w0`, it doesn't actually like it. It expects `text.width` to be a single value. So I tried to do a minimal amount of hacking to get it to work. This is kind of messy and only tested in `R version 3.0.2`. But there are two lines we need to change

```
body(legend)[[c(38,4,6)]]
# w <- ncol * w0 + 0.5 * xchar
body(legend)[[40]]
# xt <- left + xchar + xextra + (w0 * rep.int(0:(ncol - 1), 
#   rep.int(n.legpercol, ncol)))[1L:n.leg]
```

I would make sure you get the same results when running those commands, otherwise this hack won't work and may change other important code. Anyway, let's create our own version of legend with our changes

```
legend2 <- legend
body(legend2)[[c(38,4,6)]] <- quote({
    cidx <- col(matrix(1, ncol=ncol, nrow=n.legpercol))[1:n.leg]
    wc <- tapply(rep_len(w0,n.leg), cidx, max)
    w <- sum(wc) + 0.5 * xchar
    w0 <- rep(cumsum(c(0,wc[-length(wc)])), each=n.legpercol)[1:n.leg]
})
body(legend2)[[40]] <- quote(xt <- left + xchar + xextra + w0)
```

So a lot of this just reshaping the values to make sense if each label has a different length. Extra work was done to make sure columns of a legend are still all the same width (the width of the longest element). You should be able to swap out your `legend()` call with this new version, but be sure to add the `text.width` as follows

```
legend2("bottom", lty=1,lwd=1.5,ncol=4,labels,cex=1,
  col=colour,bg="white",pt.cex=1,bty="n",
  text.width=strwidth(labels, units="user"))
```

With the test data above, this should plot

[image]

I tried to change as little as possible to all other normal legend options should work (hopefully).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This is exactly what I need!!  Just wondering - if I want to change the label to only label a, b and c, how would I do this?  Or if the six graphs above have a different scale (i.e. xlim, ylim), would the code be different?

Comment: If you only want to label a,b, and c; just don't pass them all to `legend()`. Only pass in the values you want to draw in the legend. The code will not need to change if you have different scales. It should behave just like standard `legend()`.

Comment: I have just tried this on several graphs and they work wonderfully.  Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

like this for example:

```
labels<-c("GroupA","GroupB,C,D,E","GroupF", "GroupG")
strwidth(labels)
```

Comment: I did try putting the values of the widths into text.width=() but there are still problems with the spacing between the each label